# Referencing Resource Attribute in Kubernetes YAML

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

In Terraform, you can reference attributes of resources that have not yet been created in your templates, then Terraform will handle the order of resource creation (notice: aws_vpc.main.id):

```
resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

Can something similar be done in Kubernetes templates? Particularly, with service endpoints?  $(Service.myapp.endpoint) indicates my wishful syntax:

```
# --------- INGRESS CONTROLLER ---------- #
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - $(Service.myapp.endpoint)
  rules:
  - host: $(Service.myapp.endpoint)
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 80

---
# --------- SERVICE ---------- #
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
    - port: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: myapp
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Thanks

Comment: Is kubernetes creating `Service.myapp.endpoint`? What value you expect for that?

Comment: Yes.  It would be an AWS ELB domain name in this case.  Other times, might be a cluster IP.